# On rendering product details getting Error, RuntimeError: No master variant found to infer price

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, spree

Trying to render product details using spree_variants, spree_taxons, spree_prices tables by using following Query :

```
result = Spree::Product
.select('spree_products.name as product_name, spree_prices.amount as cost_price, spree_variants.sku as variant_type')
.joins("LEFT JOIN spree_products_taxons ON spree_products.id = spree_products_taxons.product_id")
.joins("LEFT JOIN spree_taxons ON spree_products_taxons.taxon_id = spree_taxons.id")
.joins("LEFT JOIN spree_variants ON spree_products.id = spree_variants.product_id")
.joins("LEFT JOIN spree_prices ON spree_variants.id  = spree_prices.variant_id")
.where('spree_taxons.name = ? AND spree_taxons.taxonomy_id = ?', 'Bags', 1)
```

Now trying to render the results collected by result  by following loop :

```
 result.each do |item|
      puts item.product_name
      puts item.cost_price
      puts item.variant_type
  end
```

Here Getting following Error message in console : 
Error :

```
Spree::Variant Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `spree_variants`.* FROM `spree_variants` WHERE `spree_variants`.`product_id` = NULL AND `spree_variants`.`is_master` = 1 ORDER BY `spree_variants`.position ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
RuntimeError: No master variant found to infer price
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably have better luck using the built in ActiveRecord functionality to manage the joins:

```
result = Spree::Product.joins(:taxons => :taxonomy)
  .includes(:master)
  .where('spree_taxons.name' => 'Bags')
  .where('spree_taxonomies.name' => 'Categories')
```

I can now do:

```
result.map { |product| [product.name, product.cost_price, product.sku] }
```

Comment: Answer is absolutely Correct. Still I have few doubts, like how by just joining Product with taxons, we got access to other tables(like prices, variants). 
2nd : What exactly happens by including:master and What is it ?

Comment: Active Record provide convenient ways to do these things.  If you just have a Spree::Product, and you try to access its price, it will query the tables to get it.  The includes function is a shortcut for fetching the master variant for all products with a single query, rather than doing one query per record.  The Active Record query interface guide is a good read for learning this sort of stuff: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html  includes is described in the "Eager loading Associations" section.